# Dois submits na mesma página

Tags: c#, html, ajax

Tenho uma página com uma lista de `checkbox` e com dois botões: Um é pra Visualizar e outro para Enviar o relatório por e-mail. Ou seja, o usuário vai selecionar os campos que ele precisa ver no relatório e ele selecionará "Visualizar" ou "Enviar". Preciso submeter o formulário porém para duas `Actions` diferentes e pegar o `FormCollection` como parâmetro. Existe alguma forma de submeter o formulário para `Actions` distintas, de acordo com o botão que o usuário apertar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traduzido de: [How do you handle multiple submit buttons in ASP.NET MVC Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/442762/1387277)

Dê um nome a cada botão de submit, e verifique esse nome no action:

```
<% Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post); %>
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Send" />
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Cancel" />
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

Controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    public ActionResult MyAction(string submitButton) {
        switch(submitButton) {
            case "Send":
                // delegate sending to another controller action
                return(Send());
            case "Cancel":
                // call another action to perform the cancellation
                return(Cancel());
            default:
                // If they've submitted the form without a submitButton, 
                // just return the view again.
                return(View());
        }
    }

    private ActionResult Cancel() {
        // process the cancellation request here.
        return(View("Cancelled"));
    }

    private ActionResult Send() {
        // perform the actual send operation here.
        return(View("SendConfirmed"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Olá @RSinohara, tem algum jeito de pegar pelo ID ao invés do Value?